# Is there a way to make a table more compact?

Tags: tables, tabularx

Is there a way to make a table more compact?
In term of the spacing between the line smaller, make the table more compact and look more professional.

[image]

MY MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XcS[table-format=-1.5]S[table-format=1.5]}
    \toprule
    & & & {\thead{Statistic}}& {\thead{Std. Error}} \\
\midrule
    \multirow{18}{*}{Difference\tnote{*}} & Mean
    & & 43.3329 & 5.238 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & \multirow{2.4}{=}{95\% Confidence Interval for Mean} & Lower Bound & 31.4839 & \\
\cmidrule{3-5}
    & & Upper Bound & \ 55.1818 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & 5\% Trimmed Mean & & 43.3857 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Median & & 45.2381 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Variance & & 274.3570 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Std. Deviation & & 16.5637 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Minimum & & 19.0476 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}    
    & Maximum & & 66.6667 \\
\cmidrule{2-5} 
    & Range & & 47.6190 \\
\cmidrule{2-5} 
    & Interquartile Range & & 30.9512 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764)

Comment: These is some vertical white space between a line of text and a horizontal line since you used `\cmidrule` from the `booktabs` package. This (and the other lines from said package)  comes with a little bit of white space around them to prevent overlapping with the text. You can see the difference if you replace one of the `\cmidrule` commands with a `\cline`. With the latter command, there will be less space between teh text and the line, making the table look more cramped.

Comment: Personally, I'd try to rearrange the table a bit and entirely get rid of the `\cmidrule` commands.

Comment: What dies the word "Difference"  in the first and otherwise empty column stand for? Couldn't one just move this information into the caption? Please also make sure that you correct the `table-format` according to the entries in your table. Using `table-format=-1.5` as currently will result in overfull box warnings and a slightly off alignment of the corresponding column(s).

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. I tried change from `\cmidrule` to `\cline`, it seemed the text a bit overlap, and tooo cramped. Very hard to make decision.

Comment: That's why I'd suggest using just the `\toprule`, `\midrule` below the headings and the `\bottomrule` below the table.

Comment: I agree with @leandriis: Bring the word "difference to the top line of the now-second column or remove it all together.

Comment: @OlegLobachev can you do an aswer, i could not get your meaning

Comment: @aan: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528029/142180 already did it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd remove all `\cmidrule` commands. Also, “Difference” seems to apply to all items, so its place is in the table header. Also I'd use the simpler `tabular*` environment, no need for the complications of `tabularx`.

I removed the last `\multirow`, which adds nothing to clarity: the blank will be easily interpreted by the reader as a cell containing the previous value.

Note `Std\. Deviation` and `Std.\ Error`, in order to avoid end-of-sentence space after the period. It could also be `Std\@. Error`, if you prefer.

The two `S` columns should be declared with `table-format=3.4` and `table-format=1.3` respectively. The minus sign is taken care of by the three digit entry for the variance. Had the variance less than 100, the format should be `-1.4` (because the minus sign is wider than a digit).

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htp]

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Whatever}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  l
  S[table-format=3.4]
  S[table-format=1.3]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Difference\tnote{*}}} & {\thead{Statistic}}& {\thead{Std.\ Error}} \\
\midrule
Mean                              &             &  43.3329 & 5.238 \\
95\% Confidence Interval for Mean & Lower Bound &  31.4839 & \\
                                  & Upper Bound &  55.1818 & \\
5\% Trimmed Mean                  &             &  43.3857 & \\
Median                            &             &  45.2381 & \\
Variance                          &             & 274.3570 & \\
Std.\ Deviation                   &             &  16.5637 & \\
Minimum                           &             &  19.0476 & \\
Maximum                           &             &  66.6667 & \\
Range                             &             &  47.6190 & \\
Interquartile Range               &             &  30.9512 & \\
Skewness                          &             &  -0.1046 & 0.687 \\
Kurtosis                          &             &  -1.4128 & 1.334 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[*] Something explaining what's going on.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Very well done table. One question, how to you move `Difference*` to be placed on `left`, and not `centre` now?

Comment: @aan `\thead[l]{Difference\tnote{*}} &`

Comment: Thanks. `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[l]{Difference\tnote{*}}} & {\thead{Statistic}}& {\thead{Std.\ Error}} \\` it seemed not working.

Comment: @egreyg, tanks It working with `{\thead[l]{Difference`. I deleted the multicolumn, is my mistake

Answer (score 1):

My main suggestion is that you get rid of all `\cmidrule` directives. Optionally, insert a bit of whitespace after every second or third row via an `\addlinespace` instruction.

Unless it's somehow vital to show 4 decimal digits in the "Statistic" column, I'd recommend showing just 3 decimal digits. `siunitx` provides some nice facilities for rounding numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
%%\centering % superfluous
%\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center} % that's the default
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
          l 
          >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
          l
          S[table-format=3.3,
            round-mode=places,round-precision=3]
          S[table-format=1.3] @{}}
\toprule
    & & & {\thead{Statistic}}& {\thead{Std.\ Error}} \\
\midrule
\multirow{13}{*}{Difference\tnote{*}} 
    & Mean & & 43.3329 & 5.238 \\
    & \multirow{2}{=}{95\% Conf.\ Interval for Mean} & Lower Bound & 31.4839 \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    & & Upper Bound & 55.1818 \\
\addlinespace
    & 5\% Trimmed Mean & & 43.3857 \\
    & Median & & 45.2381 \\
\addlinespace
    & Variance & & 274.3570 \\
    & Std.\ Deviation & & 16.5637 \\
\addlinespace
    & Minimum & & 19.0476 \\  
    & Maximum & & 66.6667 \\
\addlinespace 
    & Range & & 47.6190 \\
    & Interquartile Range & & 30.9512 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. All are good answer, is hard to select only one answer